# Summing variables with parseInt(); Not Working

Tags: javascript, variables, addition, parseint

What is the proper way to add the sum of multiple variables in Javascript?

This is what I'm trying to do. I've tried it with and without the quotes around my variables. I'm not getting a NaN or an Undefined or anything. No output whatsoever.

```
function setstat(){
document.getElementById('date').value = window.opener.document.getElementById('thisday').value;
document.getElementById('name').value = window.opener.document.getElementById('element_7').value;
document.getElementById('time').value = window.opener.document.getElementById('stwa').value;

inbcalls = window.opener.document.getElementById('element_6').value;
document.getElementById('totinb').value = inbcalls;
inbcallsp = parseInt("inbcalls",10);
asaptotal = window.opener.document.getElementById('asapcalls').value;
document.getElementById('asaptot').value = asaptotal;
asaptotalp = parseInt("asaptotal",10);
faxtotal = window.opener.document.getElementById('faxcalls').value;
document.getElementById('faxtot').value = faxtotal;
faxtotalp = parseInt("faxtotal",10);
obtotal = window.opener.document.getElementById('obcalls').value;
document.getElementById('obtot').value = obtotal;
totalcalls = inboundcallsp + asaptotalp + faxtotalp + obtotalp;
document.getElementById('totsum').value = totalcalls;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried tracing each and every one of them in the console yet?

Comment: Well, "faxtotal" isn't an int, it's a string. Without knowing what you're actually doing, tough to help. What does the JS console day?

Comment: Are the domains of the opener and the openee the same? Also, check your console for errors.

Comment: you know what, i'm retarted, ignore me. thanks anyway guys. i spend hours fixing the simplest things because i can't figure out how to use firebug. which failed to point out that "inboundcallsp" is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you quoting the variable names?

```
inbcallsp = parseInt("inbcalls",10);
```

should be:

```
inbcallsp = parseInt(inbcalls, 10);
```

And the same for the rest of them. You want to parse the value of the variables, not the names of the variables; those will always result in `NaN`.

Comment: like i said, i tried both ways. neither works, so that can't be the issue.

Comment: @pabrams: This was one problem, the other the OP fixed him/herself (wrong variable name).

Answer (score 1):

asaptotalp = parseInt("asaptotal",10);
"asaptotal" is recognize as the string not the variable
you should not quote it

Comment: i only added the quotes because it wasn't working without them. i just forgot to take them out again before posting the question. do you see anything else wrong with my code?

Comment: can u try 
totalcalls = inboundcallsp*1 + asaptotalp*1 + faxtotalp*1 + obtotalp*1;
i usually use this

Answer (score 0):

When using parseInt always specify the radix as 10.

The function singnature: parseInt(string, radix)

The radix is optional but if ommited, JavaScript assumes the following:

If the string begins with "0x", the radix is 16 (hexadecimal)
If the string begins with "0", the radix is 8 (octal). This feature is deprecated
If the string begins with any other value, the radix is 10 (decimal)

Example:
parseIn("05") ==== 0 -> true

parseIn("05", 10) ==== 5 -> true

Answer (score -1):

Don't use `ParseInt`, sometimes it will not return the proper value.

Better use `Number`, for example:

```
var i=Number(your value)
```

Comment: parseInt is the prefered way of working of course you will get "odd" values returned if you don't specify the radix parameter `parseInt(num,10)`. you also need a `new` keyword for your number to work.

Comment: Agree with above. `parseInt(num,10)` is the way to go